# How know if a user has already noted your application on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to set up a system to push the user has noted the application on the Google Play Store. Nevertheless, I would like to know if a user has already voted for my application, not to ask a second time.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API from Google that allows you to find out if a user has voted for your app.

You could make an assumption that new app installs are unlikely to be users who have already voted for your app.

So you could just store a `boolean` in `SharedPreferences` to show a popup dialog after X number of app opens if this value is `true`.

On "OK" or "Cancel" of this dialog just set this to `false` and save it and it will never load again.

Of course if the user installs the app on a different device or uninstall/reinstalls/clears data it will alert them again but I think this is rare enough to not be a problem.

Comment: My biggest problem is if the user note the application between the date of installation and date of the request. I think it's a shame, and it happens more often than you think. Thank you anyway for your answer.

Comment: People can change their votes though, I've had it happen. Make a good app, listen to customer feedback, and the rest will follow :) I've not heard people complain about 1 single popup. As long as you don't keep showing it to them, just show it once, personally I think it's fine.

Comment: Yes, but I just received the feedback report this problem ^^, hence my question.